# How to calculate double integral of a step function

Tags: integration

I would like to compute the following double integral:

$$\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^s f(r)dr\right)^2 ds$$

where $f$ is a step function of the form $f(s)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^N f_i \mathbb{1}_{I(i)}(s)$, $f_i\in \mathbb{R}$, and $I(i)=\left[\frac{i-1}{N};\frac{i}{N}\right]$ for $i\in{1,...,N}$.

I have already computed the inner integral:

$$\int_0^s f(r)dr=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^{[sN]} f_j + f_{[sN]+1}(s-\frac{[sN]}{N})$$
where [.] denotes the floor function.

So I now have to compute:

$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^{[sN]} f_j + f_{[sN]+1}(s-\frac{[sN]}{N})\right)^2 ds$$

However I am having difficulties integrating with respect to s in the previous expression.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Presumably $s<1$?

Comment: yes, $s\in[0,1]$

Comment: I have a feeling the result should be $$\frac{1}{N^3} \sum_{i=1}^N \left(\sum_{k=1}^i f_k \right)^2$$ but I cannot prove it!

Comment: Where di dthis problem come from?

Comment: It comes from a convergence problem in infinite dimensional stochastic analysis

Comment: How did you get that answer or just guessing?

Comment: @Gio_Flor: Here is the answer $ \frac{1}{3 N^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}f_i\right)^2 $.

Comment: @science no just a guess, how did you get that expression if you don't mind?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^1\left(\frac1N\sum f_i+f_{n+1}(s-n/N)\right)^2 ds\\
=\int_0^{1/N}(f_1s)^2ds+\int_{0}^{1/N}\left(\frac{f_1}N+f_2s\right)^2ds+...\\
=\frac{f_1^2/3}{N^3}+\frac{f_1^2+f_1f_2+f_2^2/3}{N^3}+\left(\frac{(f_1+f_2)^2+(f_1+f_2)f_3+f_3^2/3}{N^3}\right)+...\\
=\frac1{N^3}\left(\sum_if_i^2(N-i+1/3)+\sum_{i<j}f_if_j(1+2(N-j))\right)
$$